# How to move thumbnail to specify folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, ffmpeg, codeigniter-3

I got a thumbnail from video using ffmpeg. Right now that thumbnail stored in root folder project directory, but I want move that to specific folder. How to do that? I got a thumbnail using following...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
     <form action="upld.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
         $videoFile = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
         $imageFile = "4.jpg";
         $size = "120*90";
         $getFromSecond = 5;
         $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $getFromSecond -s $size $imageFile";
         if(!shell_exec($cmd)){
           echo "Thumbnail created";
         } else {
           echo "error while Thumbnail creating";
         }
      }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

user Codeigniter's **Image Manipulation Class**. You can find documentation here. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html

```
$filename = $this->input->post('fileToUpload');
$source_path = FCPATH . '/uploads/source/tmp/' . $filename;
$target_path = FCPATH. '/uploads/thumb/';
$config_manip = array(
    'image_library' => 'gd2',
    'source_image' => $source_path,
    'new_image' => $target_path,
    'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
    'create_thumb' => TRUE,
    'thumb_marker' => '_thumb',
    'width' => 150,
    'height' => 150
);
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
// clear //
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

This will help you.